# Can't access object key in async function when using Object-literals and switch-case, What am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, object, async-await, switch-statement, object-literal

here I tried to get a value from the function in this case my function return an object, When i try to access it with key I get "undefined" as bar1 but bar2 It's has values of a object.

```js
const foo = async()=> {
    let zoo
    let data = [
        {
            key1:"1",
            key2:"a",
            key3:3,
            key4:"cal",
        }
    ]
    
    for (const iterator of data) {
        // console.log(iterator)
            bar1 = {
                objectLiteral_swithAsync:  await objectLiteral_swithAsync(iterator["key4"]).exe1,
                objectLiterals_withOutAsync :   objectLiterals_withOutAsync(iterator["key4"]).exe1,
                switch_WithAsync : await switch_WithAsync(iterator["key4"]).exe1,
                switch_WithOutAsync :  switch_WithOutAsync(iterator["key4"]).exe1,
            }
            bar2 ={
                objectLiteral_swithAsync:  await objectLiteral_swithAsync(iterator["key4"]),
                objectLiterals_withOutAsync :   objectLiterals_withOutAsync(iterator["key4"]),
                switch_WithAsync : await switch_WithAsync(iterator["key4"]),
                switch_WithOutAsync :  switch_WithOutAsync(iterator["key4"]),
            }
            zoo = {

                bar1 :bar1,
                bar2: bar2
            }
    }
    return zoo
}

async function objectLiteral_swithAsync(param) {

    let obj=  {
       
        'cal': 2 * 2
    }[param]
    let result = {
        exe1 : obj,
        exe2: 2
    }
    return result
}

 function objectLiterals_withOutAsync(param) {
    
    let obj=  {
      
       'cal': 2 * 2
    }[param]
    let result = {
        exe1 : obj,
        exe2: 2
    }
    
    return result
}
async function switch_WithAsync (param){
    let obj
    switch (param) {
        case "cal":
            obj = 2 * 2
            break;
    
        default:
            obj =0
            break;
            
    }
     result = {
        exe1 : obj,
        exe2: 2
    }
    return result
}

function switch_WithOutAsync  (param){
    let obj
    switch (param) {
        case "cal":
            obj = 2 * 2
            break;
    
        default:
            obj =0
            break;
    }
     result = {
        exe1 : obj,
        exe2: 2
    }
    return result
}

foo().then( result=>{
    console.log('--->1',result)
})
// console.log('2', foo())
```

the result in object bar1 are undefined when its called asyncfunction with the `.` notation but in bar2 every keys has a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises don't have a `.exe1` property, yet your code is trying to retrieve such property from a promise object.

In this expression:

```
 await objectLiteral_swithAsync(iterator["key4"]).exe1
```

...the order of evaluation is as follows:

1. `iterator["key4"]` evaluates to "cal"
2. `objectLiteral_swithAsync(iterator["key4"])` evaluates **to a promise** (an `async` function returns a promise)
3. `<a promise>.exe1` evaluates to `undefined` as it accesses a non-existing property
4. `await undefined` will suspend the function to be resumed asynchronously, and then this evaluates to `undefined`

What you really want, is to have the `.exe1` access to happen when you already have awaited the promise and have the value it fulfilled with. So change the order of execution with parentheses:

```
 (await objectLiteral_swithAsync(iterator["key4"])).exe1
```

Now the order of evaluation is as follows:

1. `iterator["key4"]` evaluates to "cal"
2. `objectLiteral_swithAsync(iterator["key4"])` evaluates to a promise.
3. `await <promise>` suspends the function until the promise is resolved. When it resumes asynchronously, this expression evaluates to `{exe1: 4, exe2: 2}`
4. `({exe1: 4, exe2: 2}).exe1` evaluates to 4

```js
const foo = async()=> {
    let zoo;
    let data = [{
        key1:"1",
        key2:"a",
        key3:3,
        key4:"cal",
    }];
    
    for (const iterator of data) {
        const bar1 = {
            objectLiteral_swithAsync: (await objectLiteral_swithAsync(iterator["key4"])).exe1,
            objectLiterals_withOutAsync: objectLiterals_withOutAsync(iterator["key4"]).exe1,
            switch_WithAsync: (await switch_WithAsync(iterator["key4"])).exe1,
            switch_WithOutAsync: switch_WithOutAsync(iterator["key4"]).exe1,
        };
        const bar2 = {
            objectLiteral_swithAsync: await objectLiteral_swithAsync(iterator["key4"]),
            objectLiterals_withOutAsync: objectLiterals_withOutAsync(iterator["key4"]),
            switch_WithAsync: await switch_WithAsync(iterator["key4"]),
            switch_WithOutAsync: switch_WithOutAsync(iterator["key4"]),
        };
        zoo = {
            bar1,
            bar2
        };
    }
    return zoo;
}

async function objectLiteral_swithAsync(param) {
    const obj = {       
        cal: 2 * 2
    }[param];
    const result = {
        exe1: obj,
        exe2: 2
    }
    return result;
}

function objectLiterals_withOutAsync(param) {
    const obj = {      
       cal: 2 * 2
    }[param];
    const result = {
        exe1 : obj,
        exe2: 2
    };
    return result;
}

async function switch_WithAsync (param){
    let obj;
    switch (param) {
        case "cal":
            obj = 2 * 2;
            break;
        default:
            obj = 0;
            break;
    }
    const result = {
        exe1: obj,
        exe2: 2
    }
    return result;
}

function switch_WithOutAsync  (param){
    let obj;
    switch (param) {
        case "cal":
            obj = 2 * 2;
            break;
        default:
            obj = 0;
            break;
    }
    const result = {
        exe1: obj,
        exe2: 2
    };
    return result;
}

foo().then(result => {
    console.log('--->1', result)
});
```

Comment: thank you sir that's the answer I was looking for.